# Enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS on a specific folder?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I seem to be unable to find an answer to this, for some weird reason. I run a standard .NET MVC solution, where I need to access some static resources in a specific folder from our localhost development environment **and** the same origin. That means:

- localhost:12345 (not the same solution as website.com)
- website.com (the solution that hosts the static resources)

Both sites should be allowed to access all the files inside a specific folder hosted on `website.com`, for example `website.com/fonts`.

I've tried looking at the `<staticContent>` inside of Web.config, but so far nothing has worked out for me.

Comment: Can you try out add Permissions for Authenticated Users on your host computer? 
Right click on your folder(on windows os)-> Properties->Security->Advanced->Add full control for IIS_USR ... or something similar.

Comment: @harmath I need this to be a solution-wide thing, so everyone grabbing this from git can make it work, without doing anything else.